# what does it means "The type signature for ‘main’ lacks an accompanying binding"?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile this simple program

```
main :: IO() 
def main = do 
  putStrLn "Was lernst du?" 
  sprache <- getLine putStrLn ("Viel Erfolg beim " ++ sprache ++ " lernen!")
```

but I get the following answer in my terminal:

```
ghc --make waslernstdu1.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( waslernstdu1.hs, waslernstdu1.o )

waslernstdu1.hs:2:1:
    The type signature for ‘main’ lacks an accompanying binding
assigals-Air:documents thommymuc2004$
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove `def` before `main` in your definition. You are defining a function `def` with a single parameter `main`:

```
main :: IO() 
main = do 
  putStrLn "Was lernst du?" 
  sprache <- getLine putStrLn ("Viel Erfolg beim " ++ sprache ++ " lernen!")
```

Answer (score 2):

You have given a type signature for the `main` function (i.e. `main :: IO ()`), but you have not provided an implementation. The implementation will be of the form `main = <the implementation>`.

Comment: OK I'll show you this program

Comment: -- waslernstdu1.hs
main :: IO()
def main = do
    putStrLn "Was lernst du?"
    sprache <- getLine
    putStrLn ("Viel Erfolg beim " ++ sprache ++ " lernen!")